How can I get the value of x through a given value of y when using R language for linear regression?
I have the following data table. I have visualized it using ggplot2.
I'm wondering when y = 1, what are the respective x-axis values corresponding to the lower boundary of the standard error (se) and the regression curve?
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(114)
tableInput <- tibble(
  x = sample(60:270,100,replace = T) %>% sort(decreasing = F),
  y = rnorm(100,1,1) %>% abs(),
)

ggplot(tableInput, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 10) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(.5,2),xlim = c(50,280)) +
  theme_classic()



https://rdrr.io/cran/chemCal/man/inverse.predict.html

see this post

A solution in base R is to use optimize to find the value of x that gives the desired value of y.
We start by writing a function that will be at a minimum when the regression line is at y = 1.
f1 <- function(val) {
  mod <- lm(y ~ x, tableInput)
  pred <- predict(mod, newdata = data.frame(x = val), se = TRUE)
  (1 - pred$fit)^2
}

We can do the same for the lower border of the SE ribbon as follows:
f2 <- function(val) {
  mod <- lm(y ~ x, tableInput)
  pred <- predict(mod, newdata = data.frame(x = val), se = TRUE)
  (1 - (pred$fit + qnorm(0.025) * pred$se.fit))^2
}

Now we can use optimize to automatically find the correct x values:
x_regress <- optimize(f1, c(50, 275))$minimum
x_lower <- optimize(f2, c(50, 275))$minimum

x_regress
#> [1] 208.0677
x_lower
#> [1] 157.8854

And we can confirm these are correct by adding them as plot annotations:
ggplot(tableInput, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 10) +
  annotate('point', x = c(x_regress, x_lower), y = 1, col = 'red') +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(.5,2),xlim = c(50,280)) +
  theme_classic()



Inverting a linear function doesn't need numeric optimization. You only need to apply some highschool-level algebra: (y - coef(mod)[[1]]) / coef(mod)[[2]]. For the confidence interval I would use qt(0.025, df = mod$df.residual) in case this gets used for a model fit to a small number of observations.

@Roland thanks - that is of course true in this case. The use of numeric optimisation simply has the virtue of being applicable to a larger set of models.

Thank you for your answer. I want to know what the effect  qnorm(0.025) * pred$se.fit plays in (1 - (pred$fit + qnorm(0.025) * pred$se.fit))^2 . Why should pred$se.fit be multiplied by qnorm(0.025) ?

@tenjyosyu the ribbon shows the 95% confidence interval for the regression line. The 95% confidence interval lies between the 2.5% and 97.5% quantiles of a normal distribution whose mean is the model fit, and whose standard devation is the fitted standard error. qnorm(0.025) is equal to about -1.96, in other words it is the number of standard errors below the model fit where we will find the lower border of the ribbon.
